# On click search a webpage

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JS code that calls a json code, but now i want that the result that i click or hit "enter", that It searches an inner html page i made.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  $('#result1').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search_text').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result1').append('<li class="list-group-item "> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result1').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search_text').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result1").html('');
 });
});
```

Comment: Exactly what part of this code is not working as expected?

Comment: Put the ajax call in a named function. Then add two separate event listeners that call this function whenever someone either clicks the submit button or when someone press enter while typing in the search text field. Hopefully this points you in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/cs5e1by2/2/